# What should I read next after Neil deGrasse Tysons "Astrophysics for people in a hurry"?

Tags: astrophysics, fundamental-astronomy

I really liked the clever way the author explained stuff in this book but I already understood most of it. Neil himself states in the book that if you are not in a hurry and want to know more about the topic the are plenty of bigger books you can look into. So my question is: what is sort of a next step after this book on this topic (astronomy, astrophysics)? 
Thanks.

Comment: You would need to describe your ability at mathematics and physics to get advice.

Comment: I have a masters degree in cybernetics and robotics but when it comes to astronomy I am fairly new. I think I would be able to get around some physics and math.

Answer (score 1):

I liked Black holes & time warps by Kip Thorne. [Here's the link.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393312763) While being easy to understand, he does go into some details regarding black holes and the warping of time, which I think are interesting to the casual reader. If you have a science degree, you might not learn much new informations, but it's a good read.